# tkinter print on canvas with function

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to print a rectangle in the class mainWindow with the function OnButtonAddClick on my canvas, but when I try to I get the error:
*AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_rectangle'*

It is about the function OnButtonAddClick, but i can't see what is wrong. I tried several things now and i hope you can help me with it.

```
import tkinter as tk
import Calc as c

class mainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.Canvas()

        #more stuff

    def button(self):
        self.buttonAdd = tk.Button(self, text='Add', width=12, command=self.OnButtonAddClick).grid(column=2, row=10)

    ##more stuff

    def Canvas(self):
        "Projecting elements on canvas"
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=500, height=500, borderwidth=20, bg='white').grid(column=5, row=2, rowspan=30)

    def OnButtonAddClick(self):
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,200,200,200)
        print('hi')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    mainWindow(root).pack(side='top', fill='both')
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate layout calls from initialization calls:

```
    self.buttonAdd = tk.Button(...).grid(...)
    ...
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(...).grid(...)
```

to:

```
    self.buttonAdd = tk.Button(...)
    self.buttonAdd.grid(...)
    ...
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(...)
    self.canvas.grid(...)
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem :)